# How can I make sure scrapy-splash had render the entire page successfully

Tags: scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

Problem Occurred When I Was Crawled The Whole Website By Using splash To Render The Entire Target Page.Some Page Was Not Random Successfully So I Was False To Get The Information That Supports To Be There When Render Job Had Done.That Means I Just Get Part Of The Information From The Render Result Although I Can Get The Entire Information From Other Render Result.

Here Is My Code:

```
yield SplashRequest(url,self.splash_parse,args = {"wait": 3,},endpoint="render.html")

settings：
SPLASH_URL = 'XXX'  
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}

# Enable SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware:
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}

# Set a custom DUPEFILTER_CLASS:
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter

# a custom cache storage backend:
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

Comment: So you get your data but not all of it? Try increasing the wait argument.

Answer (score 4):

I am replying this late because the question has no answer and because it is visible on Google search.

I had similar problem and the only solution I found (besides increasing the `wait` argument, which may or  may not work, but is not reliable) is using the `execute` endpoint and custom lua script for waiting for an element. If this sounds unnecessarily complex, it is, Scrapy and Splash are not well designed in my opinion, but I have found nothing better yet for my needs.

My Lua script looks something like this:

```
lua_base = '''
function main(splash)
  splash:init_cookies(splash.args.cookies)
  splash:go(splash.args.url)

  while not splash:select("{}") do
    splash:wait(0.1)
  end
  splash:wait(0.1)
  return {{
  cookies = splash:get_cookies(),
  html=splash:html()
  }}
end
'''
css = 'table > tr > td.mydata'
lua_script = lua_base.format(css)
```

and I generate requests like this:

```
        yield SplashRequest(link, self.parse, endpoint='execute',
                            args={
                                    'wait': 0.1,
                                    'images': 0,
                                    'lua_source': lua_script,
                                })
```

It is very ugly, but it works.